# MacBook Pro (2019) 13-inch built-in-display not working

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

My MacBook Pro (2019), 13-inch, after 24 hours or something of sleeping when I opened the lid to turn it on, after showing the login screen suddenly it goes black, and after restarting the thing several times.

It not showing anything. The backlight is visible and the brightness is changeable from the touch bar. The machine is turning on and working properly but the display isn't working.

After that some time ago I connected an external display through HDMI to a Type C multiport and saw the computer is working properly.

I have upgraded the macOS Ventura 1 week ago and for the display, I have tried many methods to make it normal like SMC, and PRAM reset. Nothing works.

Now my question is, what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Likely, it could be the flex cable that connects the logic board to the display; there are known issues with this component.   It could also be a faulty display panel or a failed graphics chip or mux chip (multiplexing chip that sends video to panel, external device or both).

Your touchbar is actually a separate display device driven by a different chip altogether so what you see there is no indication of the functionality of the main graphics chip.

Regardless of what it is, it must go in for repair.